# How can I detect click on the checkbox in header dataTable

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui

I am using material-ui / data-grid
and I need to know when the user clicks on the selection of all the elements of the table, to be able to add or edit said selection function, or if there is a property that is activated when selecting the checkbox

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8jcZr.png)

Comment: Please add your code here

Comment: Without showing us the code we can't help you.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.